# Azure Disk Encryption Only OsDrive Drive Encrypts

Tags: azure

I'm using the following code to try and encrypt the disks on Windows vms, however it only encrypts the OSDisk, I set the volumetype to All, but no joy, can anyone see where I'm going wrong? This doesn't encrypt data disks. They are all premium disks on Azure.

```
$KVRGname = 'rg-svcs';
$VMRGName = 'rg-sql';
$vmName = 'vmm-sql3';
$KeyVaultName = 'main-keyvault';
$KeyVault = Get-AzureRmKeyVault -VaultName $KeyVaultName -ResourceGroupName $KVRGname;
$diskEncryptionKeyVaultUrl = $KeyVault.VaultUri;
$KeyVaultResourceId = $KeyVault.ResourceId;
$sequenceVersion = [Guid]::NewGuid();

Set-AzureRmVMDiskEncryptionExtension -ResourceGroupName $VMRGname -VMName $vmName -DiskEncryptionKeyVaultUrl $diskEncryptionKeyVaultUrl -DiskEncryptionKeyVaultId $KeyVaultResourceId -VolumeType "All" –SequenceVersion $sequenceVersion -Verbose;
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Disks need to be online and formatted within the OS before encryption

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform some [prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/azure-security-disk-encryption-prerequisites) for disk encryption. If you are using Manged disk then you need to take backup(or snapshot).  `Set-AzVMDiskEncryptionExtension` will fail if backup is not taken. `Set-AzVMDiskEncryptionExtension` cmdlet can be used to encrypt managed disks by specifying the `-skipVmBackup` parameter.
Hope this helps.